# How to read in a file, run a simulation, then read in the next file and repeat simulation

Tags: netlogo

For the code below, I am trying to serially read in .txt files created in r and output to my working directory (containing both Netlogo and R scripts) into NetLogo. The files are essentially ascii grid files whose numbers are assigned to patches to generate landscapes by coloring patches according to the numbers in grid cells from the text file. The NetLogo code executes this with a simple Setup button.

```
patches-own [
  landcover
]

to setup ; procedure to reset netlogo interface once setup button is pressed after one run of various code procedures
  ca ; clears the world
  resize-world 0 600 -600 0
  generate-landscape
  reset-ticks
end

to generate-landscape
  file-open "landscape.txt"
  foreach sort patches [
  the-patch ->
  ask the-patch [ ; read a data element into a patch variable
      set landcover file-read ; color the patch accordingly
      if (landcover = 1) [
        set pcolor green
          ]
      if (landcover = 0.5) [
        set pcolor orange
          ]
      if (landcover = 0) [
        set pcolor grey
          ]
        ]
      ]
   file-close
end
```

My question is, what if I have multiple such ascii grid .txt files in the working directory, each representing a new/different landscape and I want to read them into NetLogo to perform some simulation one at a time? Is there a good and efficient way/code to do this?

Comment: Do you want to run this sequence of experiments in BehaviorSpace? It's great for that kind of thing. You can also do it without. Which would you prefer?

Comment: @BryanHead Yes I would like to run this sequence of experiments in behavior space, but I am also interested in knowing how I can do without it. I am however most interested in figuring out how to serially read multiple files from my directory into NetLogo such that NetLogo goes through all .txt files in my directory one by one, conducting simulations on each on in NetLogo before going on the next one ... Any thoughts would be appreciated ...

Comment: @BryanHead curious to get your thoughts ...

Comment: Luke C pretty much covered what I had in mind (with minor stylistic differences). Let me know if there's anything that doesn't cover for your use case.

Comment: @BryanHead Thanks for checking in. I think Lukes answer works - details elsewhere. It would be great if you posted your answer for the benefit of noting the style differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a common filename (eg. "terrain1.asc", "terrain2.asc", etc) that you can just iterate through with `foreach` that may be easiest. Otherwise, you may be able to use the `r` extension, something like this:

```
extensions [r csv]

globals [ list-of-file-names ]

to setup
  ca
  r:eval "x <- list.files('absolute_folder_path_here')" 
  set list-of-file-names r:get "x"
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  foreach list-of-file-names [
    fname ->
    let fpath word "absolute_folder_path_here" fname
    print csv:from-file fpath
  ]
end
```

In the example above, I have three different .csv files in a folder. I provide the absolute address to that folder to the `list.files` function called in R to get the list of file names saved as a list, then I can use `foreach` to iterate over each file and do whatever you need.

```
extensions [r csv]

globals [ 
  list-of-file-names 
  numbers
]

to setup  
  ca
  r:eval "x <- list.files('C:/Users/lukepc/Google Drive/school_2017/nlogo_examples/textfiles')"
  set list-of-file-names r:get "x"
  reset-ticks
end

to scheduler
  foreach list-of-file-names [
    fname ->
    ; Reset the world
    limited-reset

    ; Load the new file/data
    let fpath word "C:/Users/lukepc/Google Drive/school_2017/nlogo_examples/textfiles/" fname
    set numbers csv:from-file fpath

    ; Do your model procedures
    go
  ]
end

to limited-reset
  ; Reset all variables (except list-of-file-names) here
  ; and otherwise return your model to its base state
end


to go
  ; Do the regular model processes as normal
end
```

**Edit:**

Stealing from Brian Head here- if he puts up this answer I will remove mine!

If you want to use BehaviorSpace, which would be far easier assuming a simple naming convention, you could do a setup like this:

extensions [r csv]

```
globals [ 
  list-of-file-names 
  filename
]

to setup
  ca
  set filename ( word "landscape" n ".txt" )
  reset-ticks
end
```

With a widget like this:

[image]

And an experiment like this:

[image]

To get an output like this:

[image]

Which shows that for each of the runs, a different `filename` was generated.

Comment: the NetLogo genius. You probably don't remember helping me with another problem in a live session a while back, but forever grateful. Long time! Thanks for the solution you provided but I find it a little confusing. Given the way the go procedure is written, how do I link the result of fpath to my generate-landscape procedure (which uses the contents of the grid file to generate a landscape) as shown in my question. I hope to generate a landscape from a file, conduct simulations with other procedures, then go on the next file and conduct simulations with other procedures, and so on ...

Comment: I am also curious to know if I use R to make my landscapes (e.g. package NLMR), is there a way to pipe the landscapes directly to NetLogo using the r extension in NetLogo instead of saving the files to the directory from R and then having NetLogo pick them up?

Comment: @nigus21 - I definitely don't know about genius, but I do remember! I tried to respond to your more recent request as well. As to this example- I recognize that what I put here is very simplistic, but without your files etc etc I wouldn't want to go to specific as I'd probably get it wrong. You would need to set it up so that within your `foreach`, your model is reset to its base state, then the new data is loaded, then the model runs- I've added a skeleton to that effect.

Comment: @nigus21 - As to your second question- I see no reason why you couldn't do that kind of data management, but it would depend on what the actual output from the NLMR package looks like- if it's not something NetLogo can understand, it may be easier to just export.

Comment: thanks for this. I am wondering if we could set up one of those live sessions, got a few more questions related to patch-based neutral landscape model generation in netlogo. Built some code and wanting to add some features and wondering what your thoughts might be. If not that's fine, but I am willing to discuss compensation as incentive.

Comment: @nigus21 - I'm open to a live session- the main issue would be scheduling a time that works for us both. I am a grad student so my hours are fairly unpredictable.

Comment: @nigus21 - Will do. For now, I've grabbed your email- feel free to remove that comment if you don't want it posted on here.

Comment: got your hangout message, replied ... a little long but provides the necessary context I think ... Looking forward to you thoughts. Thanks a million!